# Para que sirve new en javascript

Tags: javascript

Estaba probando reproducir un audio con javascript pero veo que quitando el new no sirve, entonces quisiera saber su funcionamiento y cuando usarlo.

```js
var sound = new Audio("stackoverflow.mp3");

function play() {
sound.play();
}

window.addEventListener("load", play);
```

Comment: Es una instancia de la clase audio

Comment: Agrega una breve descripción de lo que has buscado/investigado como se sugiere en [ask].

Answer (score 1):

El  operador new crea una instancia de un objeto definido por el usuario o uno de los tipos de objetos incorporados que tienen una función de construcción.

Ya que Audio() es un constructor para elementos de audio predefinido por JavaScript se debe instanciar mediante el operador new.

Acá puedes leer un poco más al respecto.

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/new

Answer (score 0):

Un *new* como su palabra lo dice sirve para crear una nueva instancia de ese objeto. Es algo parecido a Java en POO que se utiliza *new* para crear objetos de una clase.

En JavaScript no se llaman clases sino **prototipos** . Y si tu código no funciona al momento de quitar el *new* es porque no se reconoce la creación de dicho prototipo.

Comment: En JS también existe ya desde hace tiempo la sintaxis regular de poo de otros lenguajes